# sql server batch execution sequence

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server batch file containing a lot of queries like:

```
    update_query_1;
    insert_query_2;
    update_query_3;
```

The query sequence matters, meaning they should be executed one by one. My question is, will sql server automatically optimize the query by parallel processing, which might destroy the order. If so, how to ensure the sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No matter how many processors you throw at it, SQL Server will never "parallelize" across multiple statements in the same batch. It will completely finish `update_query_1` before it starts `insert_query_2`, and it will completely finish `insert_query_2` before it starts `update_query_3`.

Nothing about any of the statements in your batch is asynchronous unless you are talking about starting jobs, invoking Service Broker, or triggering some side effect. But none of these things would technically be part of this batch.